# Alphabetically order values in a Many-to-Many relation, then list_display the first item

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model as follows:

```
class talk(models.Model):
    ...
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField('speaker')
    ...
```

Which relates to the model `speaker`

```
class speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

I want to sort the speakers in class `talk` alphabetically so `speakers['charlie', 'bill', 'andy']` becomes `speakers['andy', 'bill', 'charlie']`.

Once I've done that, I have a class `talkAdmin` which looks like:

```
class talkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('slug',)
    list_display = ['title', 'speakers', 'date']
    search_fields = ['title', 'speakers']
```

This doesn't work at the moment because `list_display` doesn't accept a ManyToManyField. What I would like to do is get each object in speaker and display it in it's own column.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Talk   |Speaker   |Second Speaker|Third Speaker|
|Django |Andy      |Bill          |Charlie      |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* define a series of custom methods on the ModelAdmin, each of which returns the speaker at position X. But this would be horribly inefficient from the database point of view (each column would require a separate lookup) and not be very extensible.

Could you just have the speakers as a comma-separated list of names? That would be easy, again via a custom method:

```
class TalkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['title', 'get_speakers', 'date']

    def get_speakers(self, obj):
        speakers = obj.speakers.all().order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True)
        return ', '.join(speakers)
```

Comment: Ah! That works a lot better than I thought and efficient too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, you can either specifiy the ordering when getting the speakers for a talk, ie:

```
speakers = talk.speakers.order_by("name")
```

or set "name" as the default ordering for the `Speaker` model if that's your common use case, ie:

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    # your code here
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("name",)
```

For the second point since each talk can have from zero to virtually billions of speakers you cannot seriously expect to have one column per speaker... What you can do is add some method to your `ModelAdmin` class that returns a comma-separated (or whatever) list of speakers for each `Talk` so you still only have one single field. How to do this is fully documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: I wasn't expecting to dynamically add a column per speaker, but rather have three main speakers but I appreciate your point.